# time complexity of a recursive code

Tags: recursion, time, big-o

I need to find the complexity of this coded algorithm:

```
int f(int n){
    if ( n==0 )
       return 0;
    else if( n%2 != 0 )
       return f(n-1 ) +1 
    else
       return f(n/2) + f(n-1 ) + 1
    }
```

Can you help me determine the time complexity?

Comment: Have you run it with different inputs and watched how it effects how many times the function loops? Try sticking a print at the top and experimenting

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: First, how would this algorithm be coded as iteration?  If properly converted, the two will have the same complexity.  What did you get for expansion when you traced the execution (which you should have investigated before posting)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count

int f(int n){
    if ( n==0 )
       result = 0;
    else if( n%2 != 0 )
       result = f(n-1 ) +1 
    else
       result = f(n/2) + f(n-1 ) + 1

    count += 1
    return result
    }

// Main
for (i=0; i<=30; i+=1) {
    count = 0
    print i, f(i), count
}
```

Now, note the progression of values.  (1) Note the relationship between `f(2n)` and `f(2n+1)`  (2) Eliminate the redundant entries from #1; now note the relationships of the remaining elements; it should be obvious.

Does that get you going?